# mSata m.2 SSD not detected on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I have a Dell Latitude laptop. Its motherboard has problem and I cannot use that laptop anymore. I want to recover data from that HDD. It is mSATA SSD by Lite-On IT. I bought an Orico M.2 NGFF enclosure for it. But unfortunately it is not getting detected on any computer. It is neither showing in Bios or Disk Management.

It had Windows 7 installed but I dont know if it was encrypted or not as I cannot see that HDD on any other computer as well as can't connect and check on its original device.

Is there any other way to get my data?

Regards,
DV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally my issue has been resolved. 
I have found another laptop with the same model, I replaced SSD and copied my data.
Thank you guys for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

When Googleing "Orico M.2 NGFF Enclosure" all I can find are devices that are M.2 NVME drive enclosures.

In many cases, M.2 NVME (PCi) and M.2 SATA are not compatible.

The information page on amazon for the above enclosure state the following:

> This NVMe SSD enclosure leverages most of M.2 PCIe NVMe drives to add ultra-fast USB C 3.1 Gen 2 (10 Gbps) external storage to your USB-C enabled host (USB-C cable included)
>
> Compatible with most M-Key M.2 NVMe PCIe SSD with 2280, 2260, 2242,
>   2230 form factor: Samsung 950 Pro, PM951, PM981, SM961, 960 EVO, 960
>   Pro, 970 EVO, 970 Pro, WD Black, ADATA XPG, Crucial, Intel Optane
>   memory 600P, 760P, 900P, Kingston. **Note: NOT compatible with M.2 SATA
>   NGFF or AHCI based SSDs**.

You would need an enclosure that is compatible with some kind of M.2 SATA compatibility.

Double check the enclosure you have and read the capabilities of the enclosure. I only have the evidence from the google search with the informaiton you have offered.

Comment: Thanks TiO. This is what I ordered from Amazon: ORICO M.2 NGFF SSD Enclosure MSATA to SATA SSD Convertor for Both MSATA and M.2 B-Key SSD. I will search for the one you're suggesting.

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/ORICO-Enclosure-MSATA-Convertor-B-Key/dp/B07WYKTM6W  Googling this new info brings up this device, if this is what you have, double check that you have your drive in the correct port and disregard my original answer. There is a switch inside the unit that you need to ensure is in the correct position for the type of drive installed.

Comment: @Dhaval - Your SSD isn’t compatible.  You purchased an enclosure that only supports NVMe SSDs.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but ,will leave this here for anyone who has this problem, under windows 7, I thought the enclosure was faulty at first, the problem is the new ssd comes with gpt partition table, which win 7 can't read, the solution was I borrowed another laptop with win10 under disk management changed format to MBR, win7 can now read the disk.

Comment: “problem is the new ssd comes with gpt partition table, which win 7 can't read” - Windows 7 absolutely supports GPT. Your Windows 7 installation was configured to boot in Legacy Mode instead of UEFI.